# Parse AnyPic Facebook userId is returning nil

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I downloaded the Parse example AnyPic. I have started looking into it for some ideas for my new app that will use Parse. 
When AnyPic first opens up it requires the user to log in with facebook. I have been able to do some testing on the simulator, but now that I have started on the device I cannot log in through facebook. When I try it stays on the log in screen and just changes the log in button to log out. I have stepped through the code and found that the facebook userID is coming back nil. All the other facebook info seems to be returning values.

```
NSString *accessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
    NSDate *expirationDate = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] expirationDate];
    NSString *facebookUserId = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] userID];

    if (!accessToken || !facebookUserId) {
        NSLog(@"Login failure. FB Access Token or user ID does not exist");
        return;
    }
```

The facebokUserId comes back nil, while the others have information. I have tried hard coding the facebook user ID to what the simulator gives when it succeeds. This has not worked. I have also tried substituting my own facebook app IDs into the app to see, and it still not work.

I am new with working with social stuff, is there something I'm missing to set up facebook? Or has anyone worked with this example know how to fix it or be able to skip the facebook login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up remaking a new facebook app ID. I subbed the new info into parse and the app. I also figured out that the wrong facebook account was logged in on the device. Once I logged into the facebook account that made the new facebook app ID it worked right away.

Comment: Still experiencing this same issue. Tried creating a new Facebook app and using the new values as you describe here and getting the same thing. Bug logged at: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue when running Anypic on a device and submitted a support ticket with Facebook. They confirmed that it's an issue when signing in with the Facebook application and recommended using PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions as a workaround until they're able to look into it further. I changed the handleFacebookSession method within PAPLogInViewController.m to the code below and was finally able to login with a device!

```
- (void)handleFacebookSession {
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:)]) {
            [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:) withObject:[PFUser currentUser]];
        }
        return;
    }

    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"public_profile",
                                   @"user_friends",
                                   @"email"];

    self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

        if (!user) {
            NSString *errorMessage = nil;
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                errorMessage = @"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.";
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
            }
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                            message:errorMessage
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            if (user.isNew) {
                NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            }

            if (!error) {
                [self.hud removeFromSuperview];
                if (self.delegate) {
                    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:)]) {
                        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:) withObject:user];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                [self cancelLogIn:error];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```